# PHP variable isn't getting inserted into the database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<form action="main.php" method="POST">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
    <img type="image" id="send" src="bs.png" alt="Submit Form"/>
    <button type="sumbit">Submit</button>
</form>

<?php
$con = 
mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.co.uk",
"something","something","something");

$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO emails (email) 
VALUES ('$email')";

$run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

header("Location: result.htm");
```

(three different databases, and it just doesn't get inserted into the table..)
I've been trying to fix it for three hours, if not more. Maybe I'm just an idiot, but I don't see what is wrong.

-table name is emails

-there are 2 rows : email varchar(255) and id which is auto incremented

Comment: Check the value of `$run`. It will return `false` on failure. Call `mysqli_error()` to get a descriptive error.

Comment: I hope you weren't meaning to post the credentials to your database...

Comment: var dump or echo $email and make sure you have data.   Second, you should use prepared statements for this, third NEVER POST YOUR PASSWORD AND LOGIN INFORMATION ON STACK OVERFLOW

Comment: any error throw out?

Comment: If those are genuine database credentials I'd make sure you change them before someone uses them to gain access to it. Editing your Stack Overflow post won't stop someone being able to view the question's history and viewing them.

Comment: You have a typo; you create a variable called `$con` and then you try to use one called `$conn`. Flagging as such.

Comment: Yes the typo was the issue :D Thank you all so much!

Comment: Develop with `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` and to keep your database from being destroyed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things that could help:

## DON'T put personal credentials on stackoverflow!

**Variable check!**

```
$con = 
mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.co.uk",
"u394e","ere31","u159il");
```

has `$con`. Where

```
$run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

has `$conn`

**Backticks**

Inserting into a Database could work by using backticks. like the example below:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO emails (`email`) 
VALUES ('$email')";
```

**Check your Query**

Try putting an if statement around your query with an sql_error if it doesn't work. Example below:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO emails (email) 
    VALUES ('$email')";

    if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "<script>alert('Uw reactie is toegevoegd.')</script>";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

check the name of the variable while executing the query 
you have written $conn and while initializing the connection you have used $con

Answer (score 0):

There is an error on your code you are using wrong variable **$conn** , replace it wit $con , Try This Code. it works.

```
<form action="main.php" method="POST">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
    <img type="image" id="send" src="bs.png" alt="Submit Form"/>
    <button type="sumbit">Submit</button>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.co.uk","u1e","1","u1il");

$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES ('$email')";

$run = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

header("Location: result.htm");  
}
?>
```